# Oracle SQL Developer - How to remove double quotes in generated DDL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.   When I script out the BONUSES table under the DEPT schema, just as an example, it produces this DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE "DEPT"."BONUSES" 
(   "NEW_EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "BONUS" NUMBER DEFAULT 100
) ;
```

I don't want the double quotes to be included.  I have looked through Tools -> Preferences and am not able to find a setting to turn if "off".  Is it possibe to suppress the quotes and does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you,
Sydney

Comment: I don't think it's possible. SQL Developer uses `dbms_metadata` to get the source code, and that always generates the quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Right click your table and select "Edit"
2. Click "DDL"
3. Choose "Create"

This is different from selecting the "SQL" tag on your right panel, you get no double quotes or schema name added.

I am using SQL Developer 3.2

Comment: Unfortunately no longer works in 20.2, quotes are added too this way :(

Comment: @makrom just found out Data Modeler can do this https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/04/oracle-sql-developer-configuring-object-ddl-scripts/  it has a specific "use quoted identifiers" option   https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ddl3.png

Answer (score 1):

Victor,

Your instructions worked beautifully.

For you reading enjoyment, I found this link:

https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10628798

Doesn't this sound like the Oracle developers posted this question to their own people for comments/reviews?  :)  They should provide a setting to turn it OFF or ON.

Thanks

Comment: Those Oracle forums are open to anyone using the technology so that thread is probably not from an Oracle employee (they usually have different logos than the rest of the users)